# Does $E_{TM}$ accpets the empty word $\varepsilon$?

Tags: turing-machines, computability

Let $L = E_{TM} = \left\{  \left<M \right> | M \text{ is a TM and L(M)} = \emptyset   \right\}$.

Does $L$ accepts the empty word $\varepsilon$?

In other words, is $$\varepsilon \in L$$

I'm a little bit confused by this.

My intuition says it doesn't since the empty set rejects every input.

Comment: The answer depends on how you encode Turing machines. Which Turing machine does the empty string represent, if any?

Comment: I think it would be reasonable to _assume_ that no Turing machine has the empty string as a representation.

Comment: @PålGD Sometimes we would prefer that *any* string represent some Turing machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would answer that *no*, $\varepsilon \notin L$.

The reason is that the typical definition of a Turing machine is that its representation should contain a *non-empty* set of states and a *non-empty* tape alphabet.

In order to represent those, you typically would need a non-empty string.

*However*, as Yuval points out, you are free to define your own Turing Machine description language, and if you were to say *"We use $\varepsilon$ to denote the "empty" TM (with alphabet `0`), the TM that runs forever"*, you are free to do so, in which the answer becomes *Yes*.

I would go with *No*, $\varepsilon \notin E_{TM}$.